# Signal volume LED Array

Tags: mosfet, bjt

I am done a google search on this and have come up blank. What I have is a signal/sound being fed through a wire that ranges from (0-9V). When the volume is low, and i need 1 or 2 leds to light up, when it's high, more leds should light up. How would I solve this problem?

Since my signal fluctuates between 0 and 9V, I could use a BJT/Mosfet to set at what voltage my LED will light up yes? Basically, create a whole array of them.

By the way, I can only use discrete components for this project. No special IC's are allowed.

Comment: Why can't you use ICs???

Comment: I am allowed to use op-amps. That is all..

Comment: Can you explain how i would use op-amps to do this? Do I have to sample the signal somehow, by producing a clock signal with the op-amp?

Comment: Homework questions like this are discouraged! You need to show what you have done to solve the problem. I'd use a small MCU such as a PIC12.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=circuit%20LED%20VU%20meter&tbs=imgo:1&biw=1251&bih=652&sei=soRNUZ7dL42V0QWah4Eg#imgrc=snQi6BGhNzS3CM%3A%3BTNo262H-w5jZVM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.4qdtec.com%252FLED%252Fdiags%252Faudvu.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.4qdtec.com%252FLED%252Favu.html%3B777%3B544

Comment: why this is downvoted. I think he lacks basic knowledge about circuit configurations used inside those UV meters. But why downvote? I'm upvoting back. Reason: encouraging a newbie.

Comment: perfect. I have never heard of a VU Meter, very useful. Btw, I am a computer engineer, and many EE concepts have barely been introduced to us in our second year still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An electronic VU meter is show below so you have an idea how to "rectify" the audio before it goes into the chip.

[image]

I have circled the input where you connect your audio signal and the output is circled where you feed the rectified audio in the next circuit. Please note that I would have suggested this type of VU meter using the chip shown but because you can only use op-amps or simple components you'll have to use comparator circuits as mentioned elsewhere in this question. Alternatively this is a simple idea using diodes and transistors: -

[image]

Hopefully this is simple enough to mafe an effective LED sound meter. You can omit the opamp circuit - go straight in with the output from the rectifier circuit via a 1k resistor. As for power, the LED circuit shows it running from 13.5V nominal - it should be fine to run it at 12V or possibly a little lower.

Comment: Good explanation! worth an upvote.

Comment: +1, Good work helping new people, here and on other questions.

Comment: thanks..i wanted to use op-amps as comparators but that would be too expensive, this BJT solution is good, but I have a question:

what purpose to the diodes serve?

Comment: @user1436508 the diodes act rather like a chain of resistors, such that when about 5.4V is applied (9 diodes x 0.6V dropped across each diode) all the diodes are conducting enough to switch their respective transistors on. If (say) 2.4v is present only the first few (from the left) transistors are turned on. Progressively, as more voltage appears (at X) more diodes conduct are more transistors turn on.

Comment: What is the rectifier for?

Comment: Okay, i tried to feed the audio signal without rectification into the circuit above. the problem is none of the LEDS lit up, despite inputting a signal with varying amplifications.

The issue is even when i have no audio output, or when i tune the amplification down to 0, it still registers as an output of 5v from the output of my amplification circuit

Comment: @user1436508 where precisely did you feed the input signal in? What power supply are you using to power the circuit? Are you feeding the input via the LM324 op-amp. What are the precise differences between what I suggested and what you are doing?

Comment: i do not have rectification. is it required?

Comment: @user1436508 I didn't make the suggestion as an option.

Comment: also..i am using 9v for my op-amp and 5v as a reference at the cathode end of the op-amp.

Okay, i guess the question is if my op-amp is not suppose to have sound output, should it register as a high-voltage (5v?)

Comment: @user1436508 - this is what I said in my answer: "You can omit the opamp circuit - go straight in with the output from the rectifier circuit via a 1k resistor. As for power, the LED circuit shows it running from 13.5V nominal - it should be fine to run it at 12V or possibly a little lower." It's impossible for me to 2nd guess what you may have done that is different to what I suggested.

Comment: it seems that i had forgotten to add a capacitor to my signal output..resulting in a constant voltage. now that i have added it..only the first led seems to blink..

when there are louder sounds..more current enters my first bjt..and the led turns on. but the subsequent bjt's connected via the diodes dont seem to turn on

Comment: @user1436508 You still haven't told me what circuit you have. I don't know if you're using the op-amp or to feed stuff in or using the rectifier and cutting the track to the opamp output. There are still no guarantees you have wired it correctly. Perseverence is the key word. It hurts but that's how we all learn dude.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Andy's option, you could always go with the LM3915. Or the internal setup of the LM3915. It's just a bunch of comparators. You could even use op amps as comparators, if you wire them correctly.

[image]

Or you could use opamps.
[image]

Both of these are VU meters, and are Logarithmic, not linear.