# Why does my VU Meter work?

Tags: led, bjt

Good Day,

I was trying to build a VU meter for my audio circuit. Basically, when I have a louder sound, more leds turn on. My design looks something like this: And yes it works, but I just want to verify my theory.

1. Well, basically the signal comes into the op-amp which amplifies it about 10 times, before going to the LED array.
2. But for the second part, does it work such that when there is more voltage (louder-greater amplitude) coming out, it causes the diode to go into reverse voltage, and hence lights up the LED via the BJT? So with an even louder signal, the next diode is bypassed as well, causing the last LED to light up?

[image: My VU Meter]

Comment: I would say yes, but reverse breakdown is normally a high value, and without a part number for your diodes, it's hard to say. You could have the diodes backwards, or you could have zener or avalanche diodes.

Comment: I'd say that your diodes are shown wrongly on your diagram.

Comment: nor..if i placed the diodes the correct way..all LEDS will light up together

Comment: @user1436508 what diodes are you using? Part numbers?

Comment: The diodes are the wrong way round - your assumptions about how the circuit work are incorrect. Also, why do you have 10k in series with the left-hand LED, 1k in series with the middle LED and 330R in series with the right-hand LED? Where did you get this circuit from? I've seen circuits similar to this that run on diode forward drop but this is plain wrong

Comment: Also, why have you not followed the instructions on the original design: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61995/signal-volume-led-array/62005#62005 ? You were advised to use a rectifier circuit and you were shown one on the link. I fully explained what needed to be done.

Comment: But my signal oscillates from 0 to 9v

Answer (score 1):

You need to have followed the original instructions given to you: -

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61995/signal-volume-led-array/62005#62005)

It clearly states in that answer that you need to use a rectifier circuit. This is to convert the AC signal from the amp (or signal inputted) into a positive dc value whose peak level is roughly proportional to the peak of the AC signal.

As a matter of curiosity, if you took out the BJTs and replaced each of them with a short from base to collector does it still work? If so then you've either used PNP transistors or incorrectly wired them to the circuit.